# Some Latex/HTML codes do not work in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, tinytex

I am writing a PDF report in Rmarkdown. Some Latex codes work (\newpage) but some HTML do not (<'h1>Text</h1'>).
For example, if I use ## for headings, it works. But if I want to use , \begin{center} Text \end{center} to centralize the text does not work. I reinstalled R and Rstudio and tinytex package.
If i need to include more details, please let me know.

Example:

```
#### Company data:

##### Name: `r d1$name`;
##### Code: `r d1$code`;
##### Size: `r d1$size`;
##### Year: 2021.

This code above works. But if I want to use // to start a new line, "  "(double space) or <h4></h4> it will not work
```

Comment: I include '' in h1 to clarity the text in the question

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example that showcases your problem.

Comment: Thank you Shafee, I include an example.

Comment: `<'h1>Text</h1'>` will not work since it is HTML code, `# Text` is Markdown code and can be converted to either HTML or PDF output.